# Unity set object rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Okey, so I am taking the basics of Unity free programming course, and in one of the projects one of the extra challenges is to alternate into two camera views for a player object. Most people solved this by adding 2 cameras and switching between them. I instead, opted for moving the main camera to changing the offset of the followPlayer Method.

I used probably a not too optimal way of coding for the toggle (since I want the camera views to swap on toggle and not on holding), maybe you can help me with that too, but that's not the main question. The thing is that I added a line on the script to make so when in the alternate camera mode (First Person) when the player object rotates it also rotates the camera; but then when swaping back to the default camera the rotation is kept. That shouldn't be the case, the default camera should always be facing the same direction.I was wondering if there is a simple way of solving this (since I have never used any form of "set rotation" or anythging like that, and all the rotations I made so far are either based on other objects' rotations or in a constant rotation value each frame) or if I should just use two cameras for now. Here is the code if it is worth something:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    public GameObject player;
    public Boolean cameraKey;
    public Vector3 defaultOffset = new Vector3(0, 5, -10);
    public Vector3 alternativeOffset = new Vector3(0, 2, 1);
    public Vector3 offset;
    public Boolean cameraToggle = false; //True when alternative camera is being used

    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        cameraKey = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift);

        //If Key is pressed swithces the offset
        if ((cameraKey == true && cameraToggle == false ) || (cameraKey == false && cameraToggle == true)) //If either the camera toggle key is pressed and the default camera is activated; or if the camera toggle key is not pressed but alternative camera is activated, keeps the alternative camera
        {
            cameraToggle = true;
            offset = alternativeOffset;
            transform.rotation = player.transform.rotation; //First person camera also moves when the vehicle is rotated
        }
        else if (cameraKey == true && cameraToggle == true) //If the toggle key is pressed and the alternative camera is activated resets it to the default camera
        {
            cameraToggle = false;
            offset = defaultOffset;
            //SOMETHING HERE TO RESET CAMERA ROTATION????

        }

        //Follows "player" GameObject

        transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;

    }
}
```

Comment: If you save the initial rotation, then you can reset it.  If it had no rotation, use `Quaternion.identity` as the rotation.

Comment: How do I save the original rotation or use Quternion.identity? cause I seacrh about quaternion and it told me to really not mess around them if I don't know them properly

Comment: They mean do not alter Quaternions directly, because the math is pretty complex as it uses a fourth dimension.  To save the original rotation, set a class variable to the objects rotation in awake/start.  To use identity, simply set the rotation to Quaternion.identity.